# Error deploying jekyll to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, jekyll

I'm trying to deploy a jekyll app to heroku... it runs locally with no issues.

Here's the heroku log

```
2012-06-21T18:02:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-06-21T18:02:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-06-21T18:02:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `jekyll --server 37139`
2012-06-21T18:02:29+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: jekyll: command not found
2012-06-21T18:02:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2012-06-21T18:02:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-06-21T18:02:31+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET furious-dusk-3604.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-06-21T18:02:32+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET furious-dusk-3604.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-06-21T18:02:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H16 (Redirect to herokuapp.com) -> GET furious-dusk-3604.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=301 bytes=
```

The line

```
2012-06-21T18:02:29+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: jekyll: command not found
```

caught my attention, but I don't really know what could be the problem here. In my Gemfile I did specify

```
gem 'jekyll'
```

Cheers!

Comment: Did you generate `Gemfile.lock` and push that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using rack-jekyll with a Heroku buildpack. I had the same problem, with Heroku logging a crash. I resolved it by creating a Sinatra server as described here: [Jekyll on Heroku](http://jstorimer.com/2009/12/29/jekyll-on-heroku.html)